# Trigger `image-uploader` with vuejs from component method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code :

```
<dropdown-group
  @clickDropdownOption="clickDropdownOptionGroupBtn"                        
></dropdown-group>

<image-uploader
    :debug="1"
    class="d-none"
    ref="file"
    :maxWidth="512"
    :quality="0.7"
    :autoRotate="true"
    outputFormat="verbose"
    :preview="false"
    :capture="false"
    doNotResize="['gif', 'svg', 'pdf']"
    @change="uploadFile"
></image-uploader>
```

The function `clickDropdownOptionGroupBtn` :

```
clickDropdownOptionGroupBtn() {
    let fileInputElement = this.$refs.file;
    fileInputElement.click();
}
```

So I want to open `image-uploader` when click on drop down option but I have the error : `TypeError: fileInputElement.click is not a function`

Thx in advance.

Comment: What is the relation between fileInputElement and the clickDropdownOptionGroupBtn function and image-uploader?

Comment: it doen't matter the relation. The problem is how I can trigger `<image-uploader>` from `clickDropdownOptionGroupBtn` function

Answer (score 0):

When you have a ref from a component you can trigger any existing method from the component.

Lets assume the `submitImage` method exist inside `image-uploader`, then you can call from the parent by doing:

```js
clickDropdownOptionGroupBtn() {
    this.$refs.file.submitImage();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because the `input` is inside component : `image-uploader`. I don't know if exist a way to access this element

Comment: I've edited the answer, I guess what you want is to trigger a method inside a component.